# IOS: XMPP-Framework Message Archiving Example

Tags: ios, frameworks, xmpp

Can Anybody please help me with the XMPP-Framework for iOS ? I want to archive my Messages on the Client side. After reading a lot around the Internet i found that the XEP-0136 Modul is useful ... but i don´t now how to use it.

thanks

Comment: have you gotten any solution for the above problem, if yes then please share the same with us.

Comment: Found a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568910/storing-messages-using-xmppframework-for-ios Hope it would help you as well.