# How to integrate XMPP extension XEP 0136 for chat archiving in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xmpp, chat, xmppframework

I would like to use XMPP extension XEP 0136 for archiving purpose, but not sure how to utilize that code in my existing XMPP chat client in iOS.

Comment: @Chirstopher I have asked a straight forward question that how to integrate the XMPP extension XEP 0136, devloped for chat Archiving, not sure in what way it is incomplete or vague, it seems that you guys have not worked on XMPP iOS framework which is the reason why you didn't understand the correct terminology and recommended to closed this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568910/storing-messages-using-xmppframework-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

XEP 0136 is not client-side message archiving.so what server you are using?
if ejabberd you must add some modules to message archiving.

Comment: @Jabber XEP 0136 is indeed an extenstion for client side message archiving.

Comment: Many XMPP clients implement some form of client-side message archiving. However, it is not always convenient or even possible to archive messages locally, e.g., because it is easier to keep all archives in one universally accessible place (not scattered around on multiple computers or devices) or because the client operates in a web browser or resides on a mobile device that does not have sufficient local storage for message archiving.

Comment: In addition, server-side archiving makes it possible to offer new services such as integration of instant messaging and email. Therefore it is beneficial to define methods for server-side archiving of XMPP messages.

Comment: @Chirstopher: WHY? can you show me atleast one answer  you have done  in XMPP or ejabberd.i see your answers randomly.maybe im wrong?

Comment: @Jabber Well said, Christopher and other guys who closed this thread never explored XMPP iOS framework, I have gotten a workaround to enable XEP 0136 in my code.

Comment: @sandy : hey man i just implement the XMPPMessageArchiving to save the chat. but i just want to fetch that and want to show in chatview. if u have don that then please help me for that