# XMPP framework XEP-0136 implementation in iOS client

Tags: ios, xcode, xmpp, xmppframework

I am working on the iOS chat client application. Now I want to store the chat history in the device and server, I looked in the google and found that I can do it with the XEP-0136 extension. I looked into it but didn't got any idea about how to implement.
If anyone has used or have any link to tutorial which can help me than please share it.

I have now activated the message archive module and seems like its storing the message but don't know where it is storing. Can anyone let me know where in local device is the archived message are stored.

following is the code I have used for the module activation.

```
XMPPMessageArchiving *xmppMessageArchivingModule = [[XMPPMessageArchiving alloc] initWithMessageArchivingStorage:[XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage sharedInstance]];

[xmppMessageArchivingModule setClientSideMessageArchivingOnly:YES];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule activate:xmppStream];
[xmppMessageArchivingModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Finally I found answer at in this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568910/storing-messages-using-xmppframework-for-ios

Comment: how to get chat history ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get some solution by seeing this tutorial.Refer this tutorial.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already implemented the chat view and other things, Now I want to store the message in the device. Noting related it is given in this link.

Answer (score 1):

All archived messages will be store in XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject Table. Even offline messages too.